# Append a group of content in text file to a list by keyword

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a text file which have following content and how could I group each line to an independent list? (**Edited** ~ Append each group of lines into an independent list, for example, list of groupA and list of groupB)

```
Group A
John 25 USA
Ali 20 Indonesia
Christina 30 India
.
.
Group B
Chris 30 Australia
ZhangMing 20 China
.
.
.
```

The output should be like this

```
print groupA
# output
[['john','25','USA'], ['Ali','20','Indonesia'], ['Christina','30','India']]

print groupB
# output
[['Chris','30','Australia'], ['ZhangMing', '20','China']]
```

So far I am able to append each line as a list of words into a list, but have no idea to automatic grouping them according to Group.

Appreciate if anyone could advise.

Comment: Are there literally lines with `.` in the file or did you use them to abbreviate?

Comment: It means "more" rows, sorry for confusing

Answer (score 0):

The way to group like this is to maintain two lists, an outer list for all the groups and an inner list for the individual groups.  Each time a group is collected, and the group to the "outer" list and start a new group list.

```
with open('groups.txt') as f:
    groups = []
    group = []
    for line in f:
        if line == '.\n':
            continue
        if line.startswith('Group'):
            if group:
                groups.append(group)
                group = []
            group.append(line.strip())
        else:
            group.append(line.strip().split())

    # Collect the final group, if there is one
    if group:
        groups.append(group)

print(groups)
```

Result:

```
[['Group A', ['John', '25', 'USA'], ['Ali', '20', 'Indonesia'], ['Christina', '30', 'India']],
 ['Group B', ['Chris', '30', 'Australia'], ['ZhangMing', '20', 'China']]]
```

Edit, based on changed question:

Creating new variables in the global namespace is possible, but usually not a good idea (it's not possible to tell whether `Group_A` is a mistake or has been conjured out of some data).  The best approach is to create a container (a list or dict ) to hold the values, and access them in the container.

This example uses a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to hold the generated lists.

```
from collections import defaultdict                                                                                                                                              


with open('groups.txt') as f:                                                                                                                                                    
    groups = defaultdict(list)                                                                                                                                                   
    group = []                                                                                                                                                                   
    for line in f:                                                                                                                                                               
        if line == '.\n':                                                                                                                                                        
            continue                                                                                                                                                             
        if line.startswith('Group'):                                                                                                                                             
            key = line.strip()                                                                                                                                                   
        else:                                                                                                                                                                    
            groups[key].append(line.strip().split())                                                                                                                             

print(groups)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I wish to have each Group in a list, for example, list of Group A and list of Group B, I have edited my question, apologize for confusing

Comment: I've amended my answer based on your comment; if it's what you want, please leave a comment and I'll close the question as a duplicate - this gets asked a lot here

Comment: How should i access the single value in the value list? Let say, to assess if John in Group A from USA, then do something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try of series grouping, if you have flexibility of pandas

```
text = pd.Series(text.splitlines())
text.groupby(text.str.contains('Group').cumsum()).apply(lambda x: x.str.split(' ').tolist()[1:])
```

Out:

```
1    [[John, 25, USA], [Ali, 20, Indonesia], [Chris...
2     [[Chris, 30, Australia], [ZhangMing, 20, China]]
dtype: object
```